# How To make my image show on my Website using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a simple website from a tutorial I saw on YouTube, and I am currenlty trying to add 2 images, but they aren't showing. I am using Visual Studio Code.

On VS I put the images in my images folder: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9G3zx.png)
And the result is supposed to look like this: [the expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HViuz.png)
But it currenlty looks like this: [Reality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miB3x.png)

I am not sure if it's my code or if I put my images in the wrong place. Could someone review my code just in case?

```
HTML: 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>NEXT Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f1408164ca.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kumbh+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
   <nav class="navbar">
   <div class="navbar__container">
    <a href="/" id="navbar__logo"<i class="fas fa-gem"></i> NEXT</a>
    <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
    </div>
    <ul class="navbar__menu">
        <li class="navbar__item">
            <a href="/" class="navbar__links">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__item">
            <a href="/tech.html" class="navbar__links">Tech</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__item">
            <a href="/" class="navbar__links">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__btn">
            <a href="/" class="button">Sign Up</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
   </div>
</nav>

<div class="main">
    <div class="main__container">
        <div class="main__content">
            <h1>NEXT GENERATION</h1>
            <h2>TECHNOLOGY</h2>
            <p>See what makes us different.</p>
            <button class="main__btn"><a href="/">Get Started</a></button>
        </div>
        <div class="main__img--container">
            <img src="images/pic1.svg" alt="pic" id="main__img">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="services"> <br><br><br><br>
    <h1>See what the hype is about</h1>
    <div class="services__container">
        <div class="services__card">
            <h2>Experience Bliss</h2>
            <p>AI Powered Technology</p>
            <button>Get Started</button>
        </div>
        <div class="services__card">
            <h2>Are you ready?</h2>
            <p>Take the leap</p>
            <button>Get Started</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


CSS:
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
    background: #131313;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

.navbar__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 50px;
}

#navbar__logo {
    background-color: #ff8177;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ff0844 0%, #ffb199 100%);
    background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.fa-gem {
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

.navbar__menu {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar__item {
    height: 80px;
}

.navbar__links {
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    height: 100%;
}


.navbar__btn {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    width: 100%;
}


.button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #f77062;
    color: #fff;
}


.button:hover {
    background: #4837ff;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar__links:hover {
    color: #f77062;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .navbar__container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        height: 80px;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1300px;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .navbar__menu {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: -1000px;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        height: 50vh;
        z-index: -1;
        background: #131313;
    }

    .navbar__menu.active {
        background: #131313;
        top: 100%;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        z-index: 99;
        height: 50vh;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
    }

    #navbar__logo {
        padding-left: 25px;
    }

    .navbar__toggle .bar {
        width: 25px;
        height: 3px;
        margin: 5px auto;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        background: #fff;
    }

    .navbar__item {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .navbar__links {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 2rem;
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
    }

    #mobile-menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20%;
        right: 5%;
        transform: translate(5%, 20%);
    }

    .navbar__btn {
        padding-bottom: 2rem;
    }

    .button {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 300px;
        height: 60px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .navbar__toggle .bar {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }


    #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(2) {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(1) {
       transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
    }

    #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(3) {
        transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
     }
}

.main {
    background-color: #141414;
}

.main__container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    align-items: center;
    justify-self: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 90vh;
    background-color: #141414;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    padding: 0 50px;
}

.main__content h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
    background-color: #ff8177;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ff0844 0%, #ff1b19 100%);
    background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.main__content h2 {
    font-size: 4rem;
    background-color: #ff8177;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #b721ff 0%, #21d4fd 100%);
    background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.main__content p {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
}

.main__btn {
    font-size: rem;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #f77062 0%, #fe5196 100%);
    padding: 14px 32px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.35s;
    outline: none;
}

.main__btn a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.main__btn:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: #4837ff;
    transition: all 0.35s;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.main__btn:hover {
color: #fff;
}

.main__btn:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    }

    .main__img--container {
        text-align: center;
    }

    #main__img {
        height: 80%;
        width: 80%;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .main__container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: auto;
            align-items: center;
            justify-self: center;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            height: 98vh;
        }

        .main__content {
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 4rem;
        }

        .main_content h1 {
            font-size: 2.5rem;
            margin-top: 2rem;
        }

        .main__content h2 {
            font-size: 3rem;
        }

        .main__content p {
            margin-top: 1rem;
            font-size: 1.5rem;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        
        .main_content h1 {
            font-size: 2rem;
            margin-top: 3rem;
        }

        .main__content h2 {
            font-size: 2rem;
        }

        .main__content p {
            margin-top: 2rem;
            font-size: 1.5rem;
        }

        .main__btn {
            padding: 12px 36px;
            margin: 2.5rem 0;
        }
    }

    .services {
        background: #141414;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
    }

    .services h1 {
        background-color: #ff8177;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ff8177 0%, #ff867a 0%, #ff8c7f 21%, #f99185 52%, #cf556c 78%, #b12a5b 100%);
        background-size: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 5rem;
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        -moz-background-clip: text;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
    }

    .services__container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .services__card {
        margin: 1rem;
        height: 525px;
        width: 400px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, 
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, 
        rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.6) 100%
        ), 
        url('/images/pic3.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .services__card:nth-child(2) {
        background-image: linear-gradient(
            to bottom, 
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, 
            rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.6) 100%
            ), 
            url('/images/pic4.jpg');
    }

    .services h2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 350px;
        left: 30px;
    }

    .services__card p {
        position: absolute;
        top: 400px;
        left: 30px;
    }

    .services__card button {
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background: #f77062;
        position: absolute;
        top: 440px;
        left: 30px;
        font-size: 1rem;  
    }
```

Comment: Please reduce your problem to an [mcve] (emphasis on the minimal) and do some basic debugging (like using the Network tab of your browser's developer tools to make sure the image is being requested and seeing what response you get for it).

Comment: Pay attention to the descriptions of the tags you select for your questions. You've tagged this as [tag:web] which says "Do not use this tag".

Comment: It's the path to your image that must be wrong. In the rule `.services__card` if you replace `background-image: linear-gradient(...), url('/images/pic3.jpg');` with a placeholder image (e.g. https://placekitten.com/200/300) then an image displays with no problem.

Comment: @Adam, on VS code I put the images in the "images" folder like I showed on the screenshots, its supposed to show the image since I put "url('/images/pic3.jpg');". And I am not really sure what you mean by "placeholder image".

Comment: A placeholder image is an image that you can use from various websites to simulate your user's/customers images during development. Have a look at https://placehold.co/ or https://picsum.photos/

Answer (score -1):

You can use the img tag to display an image on your website.
Here’s an example:

```
<img src="path/to/image.jpg" alt="Image description">
```

You can use the content property to display an image on your website.
Here’s an example:

```
div::before {
  content: url('path/to/image.jpg');
}
```

Comment: "You can use the img tag to display an image on your website" — They are. Telling them to do what they are doing already doesn't help them solve the problem.

Comment: `alt="Image description"` — No. The alt attribute should be a replacement for the image if the image doesn't display. Sometimes that is a description of the image, but not always or even often.